# TFS Suggested Values in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, tfs

I'm using Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity to represent the activities in customized work items; for each one of these work items I have a set of different suggested values for the activity field.

now the problem is that in when I try to create a report with an activity filter using SSRS some of the suggested values are missing.

for example:
in TFS I have: Activity-1, Activity-2 and Activity-3
in SSRS I only have: Activity-1 and Activity-3

I've tried to rebuild the warehouse database but still there are missing values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted the same question in MSDN forums and [here is their answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsreporting/thread/d7058d27-3765-4f9f-93be-8db80a13265f#770bdc43-963c-4267-a1ca-a286b99a90bc)